# Using psycopg2 to get a value in table with Key Value

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to use `psycopg2` to read `Postgres`.

I am reading from a database table called deployment and trying to handle a Value from a table with three fields id, Key and Value.

One of the keys is `LIST_CONFIG` and it has the Value as following:

```
    list_config: {     
             "configone":{
                "disk_size":100,"machine_type":"large","region":"us-west-1"},
             "configtwo":{
                "projectname":"project","zone":"us-east1-b"}
             }
```

I am trying to get region for `list_config.configone.region` (which is us-west-1)

I get the above `list_config` by running the following code:

```
    import psycopg2
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database=database, user=user, password=password)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT \"Value\" FROM deployment WHERE (\"Key\" = 'LIST_CONFIG')")
    row = cur.fetchone()
    print(row[0])
```

I am not able to get the `list_config.configone.region` even after doing the following:

```
    row = cur.fetchone()
    config = row[0]
    print('config: %s', config["configone"])
```

I got the error 
`Arguments: (TypeError('string indices must be integers',),)`

I also tried the following

```
    row = cur.fetchone()
    config=row[0]
    args=namedtuple('row',config.keys()).*config.values())
    print('args: %s', args)
```

This gave the error `Arguments: (AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'keys'",),)`

Is there a way to use cursor_factory=DictCursor which would return a dict instead of Tuple?

++ Editing with solution - Following is what what worked for me in the end++

I found out eventually that row is a tuple and row[0] is a string. Hence I used json.loads on row[0] to convert it to a json object. Then I was able to print the region

```
    row = cur.fetchone()
    config_json = json.loads(row[0])
    region = config_json['configone']['region']
    print('Region: %s', region)
```

Comment: `for val, desc in zip(row, cur.description) ... print("row[{0}]={1}".format(desc, val))`

Comment: What's the output you get from `print(config: %s', config["configone"])`?

Comment: @MFisherKDX, I don't see the output that I want here, all this does is print the description ```row[Column(name='Value', type_code=25, display_size=None, internal_size=-1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None)]``` followed by the value that I already got by printing row[0] which is the entire dict

Comment: @kerwei, I get ```Arguments: (TypeError('tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str',),)``` from ```print(config: %s', config["configone"])```

Comment: It prints the description of the column and the value at that column. Your comment is missing the value. What is the output of `print(row[0])`? The statement: `print(config: %s', config["configone"])` is not even valid syntax. You are missing a single quote: '.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I fixed the code in original question. When I tried ```for val, desc in zip(row, cur.description) ... print("row[{0}]={1}".format(desc, val))```, it did print the description and the entire list_config along with it. I am trying to print just list_config. configone.region

Comment: I suppose your Value column is set up as the CHAR datatype? The cursor is returning exactly just that - a string with json-like structure. You will need to parse this string separately to unpack the values. Otherwise, you can maybe use the array data type but it looks complicated to me, in my opinion.

Comment: I would think that it's better to redesign your table, if you require more modular queries like above. Unpack your original list_config value and store them in separate columns. It's so much easier to query that way and you get the benefit of indexing as well, if one of the fields is heavily queried